# why my table goes beyond the page border?

Tags: latex, longtable

I am out of any ideas. My piece of code for a very long table goes beyond the page border. I spent 4 hours reading through and testing all possible solutions but no success:

Here is the example screenshot from the word:
[image]

below is a snippet of my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, tabu,pdflscape,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{|p{2.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{2cm}p{4cm}p{3.5cm}|}
\caption{lab lab lab}
\label{table:test}\\
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\textbf{Geospatial domain}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\textbf{E-government / open data platform}} \\ \cline{2-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\textbf{Requirements for the catalogue}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\shortstack[l]{Munich Geoportal \\ - Data Model: ISO 19139 \\ - Software: Geonetwork}} &

  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\shortstack[l]{GeoportalBayern\footnote{\url{https://geoportal.bayern.de/geoportalbayern/suche/suche?6\&q=flur\&f=true}} \\ - Data Model: ISO 19139 \& Inspire\ \ - Software: privately developed}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\shortstack[l]{European Data Portal - EDP\footnote{\url{https://data.europa.eu/en}} \\ - Data Model: DCAT-AP \\ - Software: CKAN}} &
  \shortstack[l]{City of Los Angeles\footnote{\url{ https://data.lacity.org/browse}} \\ - Data model: Socrata native data model \\ - Software Socrata} \\ \hline
\endhead

\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}1. Intuitive \& User friendly web interface} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}Yes} &
 \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}\shortstack[l]{Partial \\ {[}- only available in German \\ - not trivial{]}}} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}Yes} &
 \cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}\shortstack[l]{Partial\\ {[}- some dataset pages are long{]}} \\ \hline

\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}Fundamental register (e.g. Building, Agricultural land parcel)} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9CCDE2}} &
   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}} &
   \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I set the linewidth, did not work. I also used other libraries such as tabularx, still could not figure it out.
Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks
Mani

Comment: If you warp your cells in `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...}` you disable the widths you set at the start of the table. Remove all these unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...}`

Comment: They are not necessary at least from my understanding. I will update my post with a word  example I have.

Comment: They are completely and utterly unnecessary and prevent latex from properly formatting your table. Whatever online table converter you used to produce this code, should stop using them. It makes no sense to merge a single cell into a single cell.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. You are right, I used an online tool. My problem was that I could not design the table on my own in particular due to the merged columns in the header. Do you have any tips for me on how I can manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you warp all your cells completely unnecessarily into `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...}` you disable the automatic line breaking and sabotage the columns width you set at the start of the table.

Here a different approach using the `tabularray` package, which makes it very easy to merge cells:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{9CCDE2}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption={lab lab lab},
  label={table:test},
  note{1}={\url{https://geoportal.bayern.de/geoportalbayern/suche/suche?6&q=flur&f=true}},
  note{2}={\url{https://data.europa.eu/en}},
  note{3}={\url{https://data.lacity.org/browse}}
]{
  colspec={XXXXX},
  cells={halign=l,valign=h},
  row{odd}={mycolor},
  row{1}={white,font=\bfseries},
  rowhead = 2,
  vlines,hlines
}
\SetCell[r=2]{} Requirements for the catalogue & \SetCell[c=2]{} Geospatial domain & & \SetCell[c=2]{} E-government / open data platform & \\
& {Munich Geoportal \\ - Data Model: ISO 19139 \\ - Software: Geonetwork} & {GeoportalBayern\TblrNote{1} \\ - Data Model: ISO 19139 \& Inspire\\ - Software: privately developed} & {European Data Portal - EDP\TblrNote{2} \\ - Data Model: DCAT-AP \\ - Software: CKAN} & {City of Los Angeles\TblrNote{3} \\ - Data model: Socrata native data model \\ - Software Socrata}\\
... & .... & ... & ... & ...\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]